# How to use Full calender validRange

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to use ValidRange in FullCalender. I looked at the docs. But can't get it to work. The events are renderd, but not the `validRange`. I am using the `week` view.
My Code:

```
     jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        validRange: {
            start: '2017-12-01',
            end: '2017-01-24'
        }
    });
```

I tried:

```
  jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      validRange: {
                start: moment('2017-12-01'),
                end: moment('2017-01-03')
            }
          }
     jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
     jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', items);
```

but it still dosen't work. I tried to add the options like this:

```
  jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

     jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            validRange: {
                start: moment('2017-12-01'),
                end: moment('2017-01-03')
            },
            addEventSource: items


        });
```

but then nothing showed. Any suggestions?

Comment: "the events are renderd, but not the validRange".  What do you mean by this? What events are you talking about? As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/validRange/, specifying a "valid range" is a UI-related option which is intended to prevent the user from dragging or resizing events into the dates specified in the range. Is that what you're doing? This option has nothing to do with where the events which come from a server event source are placed - that's entirely determined by the dates which are within those individual events.

Comment: It would help also if you clarified what you mean by "doesn't work" and "nothing showed". Some of your syntax and option names look like they are not valid - have you checked in the docs for the proper options to use, and have you checked in your browser's console for any Javascript or network errors?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the standard technique for setting options dynamically from the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/visibleRange/)

```
 jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'validRange', {
        start: validStart,
        end: validEnd
    });
```